PATCH Request vs PUT Request (in ASP.NET Core Web Api)
I had a question about the patch request.
We all know that put requests are used for general updates to an object and patch requests are used for minor updates.
In patch requests, can't we check which fields are populated and just update them?
In this case, we don't need to use the patch anymore, right?
For Example in this code, we checked null fields and don't updates them :

        [HttpPut("{todoId}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateTodoItem(int todoId , TodoItemUpdateDto todoDto)     
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var todo = await _context.TodoItems.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == todoId);

                if (todo == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                if(todoDto.Name != null)
                    todo.Name = todoDto.Name;

                if(todoDto.Description != null)
                    todo.Description = todoDto.Description;

                if (todoDto.IsComplete != null)
                    todo.IsComplete = todoDto.IsComplete.Value;

                _context.TodoItems.Update(todo);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return NoContent();
            }

            return BadRequest();
        }

   

    public class TodoItemUpdateDto  
    {
        [MaxLength(30 , ErrorMessage = "Name has max length 30")]
        public string? Name { get; set; }    
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public bool? IsComplete { get; set; }

    }


The defacto standard for PATCH behavior is described in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902.html. Yes you COULD implement your own PATCH based on partial updates. But how would you set Name to null? You would have to use a PUT.

PUT: This method can be called multiple times with the same effect as calling it once. PUT is typically used to replace a resource entirely. If only partial data is provided, fields not included are usually set to null or their default values unless explicitly programmed otherwise.
PATCH: Unlike PUT, PATCH is used for making partial updates, i.e., only the fields that are mentioned in the request payload are updated. Fields not included in the request should remain unchanged. This method is not idempotent, which means subsequent identical requests may have different effects.
The PUT and PATCH methods are used to update an existing resource. The difference between them is that PUT replaces the entire resource, while PATCH specifies only the changes.in your example you are implementing a PATCH-like behavior using a PUT request. This method checks if specific fields in the DTO (Data Transfer Object) are non-null and only updates those fields in the database, leaving other fields unchanged if they are not provided. This selective update mechanism mimics what a PATCH request would typically do.
You check if each field is non-null before updating. This prevents overwriting values with nulls or defaults, which is crucial for not losing data in fields that the client did not intend to update. The choice to implement this pattern under a PUT endpoint isn't wrong, but it's unconventional. It could lead to confusion among API consumers who expect PUT to replace the entire resource and PATCH to support partial updates.Using PATCH would be more appropriate.
